# Identity for symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I have encountered an identity for a symmetric matrices of the form $A=BB^T$ where $B\in \mathbb{R}_{n\times m}$, of the form:

$$ A=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \mathbf{u }_i \cdot \mathbf{u}_i^T \quad \text{for appropriate vectors} \quad \{ \mathbf{u}_i  \}_{i=1}^m $$

I can't explain to myself why this identity is true, and as a consequence to verify it. So my question is whether the identity is correct, and what are these appropriate vectors. I would also appreciate corrections, if this identity is incorrect but is similar to a valid one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your identity is correct and can be deduced as a consequence of [block-matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_multiplication). In particular, we have
$$
BB^T = \pmatrix{u_1 & \cdots & u_n}\pmatrix{u_1^T \\ \vdots \\ u_n^T} = 
\sum_{i=1}^n u_iu_i^T
$$
where $u_i$ denotes the $i$th column of $B$.